# Chef - Looping through hosts to create cron jobs

Tags: loops, cron, chef-infra

How do I loop through a number of hosts using the chef search function and apply my cron job to all the nodes it finds.  I tried using the variable option as used in the templates and it didn't work. SO all webservers get the entry when they run it.

```
mynodes search(:node, 'tags:webservers')

cron "noop" do
hour '5'
minute '0'
command "/bin/true"
end
```

Comment: did you try `mynodes.each do |next_node|` to loop through the results?

Comment: Yes and it worked.  That was the missing element.  A little ruby goes a long way!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to loop through the results of a search is to use plain old ruby.

```
mynodes.each do |next_node|
  do stuff
end
```